# ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION not redirected to the app page in Api 30

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

To request a user for granting "Allow display over other apps" permission, one can send an `Intent` with `Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` action. For Android versions before R, (API version < 30) it goes directly to this specific setting in app setting page, but for API 30, it goes to "Display over other apps" permission page which is very bad for user experience.

I read that it's an intended behavior, but is there a workaround for this? For my screenshot app which needs to display a capture overlay button, what alternatives exist?

Comment: "For my screenshot app which needs to display a capture overlay button, what alternatives exist?" -- on Android 11+, you could switch to a bubble notification.

Comment: I read some docs about it (didn't go very deep) and it seems very opinionated in being used for conversions. If you have experience working with its API, do you actually recommend it to my use-case?

Comment: I am certain that Google intends it for chats. I am certain that developers will use it for other things.  I used it to be able to switch between a set of presentation slides and an app that I was demoing. To flip it around, overlays are already being restricted (e.g., Android One), and I fully expect them to be completely blocked in some future Android release. My expectation is that developers will be steered towards bubbles if they want that sort of overlay-style trigger mechanism.

Comment: Seems a lot of try and error is ahead! Thank you for your information, if you had time to write an answer, I would accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I read that it's an intended behavior, but is there a workaround for this?

I am not aware of any.

> what alternatives exist?

You could use [bubbles](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/bubbles) on Android 11+.

Long-term, I expect that overlays are going to be removed as an option. They are already limited in some environments (e.g., Android One), and there has been a steady move to eliminate these sorts of things (e.g., custom toasts). Unless Google comes up with something else, my guess is that apps that use an overlay for a trigger mechanism — which sounds like your scenario — will wind up migrating to bubbles or simply persistent notifications.

Note that bubbles have some UI beyond the bubble itself — tapping the bubble displays an activity in a pop-up window. That might or might not fit your use case.

And, FWIW, [this sample module](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-r/-/tree/vFINAL/BubbleConversation) demonstrates how to show a bubble.

Comment: My current approach is to hide the button, capture screenshot and show it again. Seems bubble is not very suitable for that. Sticky notification is slightly better but still inconvenient. I'm thinking of other ways like shaking the device, which is pretty silly :D

Comment: Bubbles are ONLY intended for chats. Maybe you could get rejected if you misuse the API